# How do I remove these "phantom" nvidia modules

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am trying to completely remove nvidia drivers from my computer and I'm stumped. I think I must have installed them in a weird way because nothing seems to be working.

To remove the nvidia drivers, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Next I unloaded all of my nvidia modules:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia
```

Which works fine.

To check that nvidia is gone I ran the following commands:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
dkms status | grep nvidia
apt list --installed | grep nvidia
```

All of these return nothing, so far so good.

But then when I reboot and run:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

I get:

```
nvidia_drm             45056  0
nvidia_modeset        860160  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              13139968  1 nvidia_modeset
```

It's a serious problem because these "phantom" modules are interfering with me getting nvidia to work. Whenever I install a new version of nvidia, it appears to load these old modules. Then when I run `/usr/bin/nvidia-srm` I get the error `Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`.

Because of this problem, xorg wont' load

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. In short: I was booting into an old kernel.

I use a program called Grub Customizer which lets me enter custom startup entries. I forgot that the main grub entry I boot from had a hard-coded reference to kernel version `4.13.0-36-generic`. Once I updated that reference to the newest version, `4.13.0-43-generic` and rebooted, that solved my problem.

Comment: I think `sudo update-initramfs -u` would have fixed it with the old kernel as well.

Comment: stupid question: How do i mark this thread as solved? I'm not seeing the "Thread Tools" panel

Comment: There is a "tick" sign at the left of the answer. This is not a forum but Q&A site.